# Find the Gaussian and mean surface curvature of a circular cylinder of radius $a$

Tags: differential-geometry

**Find the Gaussian and mean surface curvature of a circular cylinder of radius $a$**
$$\begin{cases}
x=a\cos v\\ 
y=a\sin v\\ 
z=u
\end{cases}$$

The standard approach I chose to solve this problem. I found the first and second derivatives of the parametric surface equation by the parameters $u$ and $v$. First, we find the first derivative
$$\begin{cases}
x_u=0\\
y_u=0\\
z_u=1
\end{cases}, \ \ 
\begin{cases}
x_v=-a\sin v\\
y_v=a\cos v\\
z_v=0
\end{cases}$$
Now find the second derivatives:

$$\begin{cases}
x_{uu}=0\\
y_{uu}=0\\
z_{uu}=0
\end{cases}, \ \ 
\begin{cases}
x_{uv}=0\\
y_{uv}=0,\\
z_{uz}=0
\end{cases}, \ \ 
\begin{cases}
x_{vv}=-a\cos v\\
y_{vv}=-a\sin v\\
z_{vv}=0
\end{cases}$$

After I have found the derivatives, I can find the covariant derivatives, which I found using the formula
$$E=x_u^2+y^2_u+z^2_u=1$$
$$F=x_ux_v+y_uy_v+z_uz_v=0$$
$$G=x_v^2+y_v^2+z^2_v=a^2$$
$$L=x_{uu}x_u+y_{uu}y_{u}+z_{uu}z_u=0$$
$$M=x_{uv}x_u+y_{uv}y_u+z_{uv}z_u=0$$
$$N=x_{vv}x_v+y_{vv}y_v+z_{vv}z_v=0$$

Now by the formulas, I can calculate the Gaussian curvature and the average curvature, respectively
$$K=\frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F^2}=0, \ \ H=\frac{1}{2}\frac{EL+GN-2FM}{EG-F^2}=0$$

*Could you check if I used the formulas correctly and calculate the curvature?*

Comment: The mean curvature of a cylinder cannot be $=0$.

Comment: Why? A circular cylinder is a surface with constant curvature, namely with zero curvature. This means that at each point of the circular cylinder surface both principal curvatures are zero, hence their product is also zero. Isn't it?

Comment: The product yes. The mean no. Only one principal curvature is zero.

Comment: Could you show me where I made a mistake? And this question: am I using the correct formulas to calculate the Gaussian curvature and the average curvature?

Comment: There must be an error in your formula or calculation for $N$. And no, I don't want to check the details, sorry.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the mistake was really in calculating $N$, it wouldn't be zero, it would be $a^2$.

Comment: Your formula for $L, M, N$ are wrong.

Comment: Why? What are the right ones then?

Comment: Check your note again.